# How can I secure data using Vue.js and Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, encryption, nuxt.js

How can I keep api keys and other sensitive data served on the front end secure?

I'm thinking of proposing a move from WordPress to vue/nuxt/cloud firestore/storyblok, but security will have to be equal if not greater for management to approve it.

I realize that I can whitelist IP addresses and domains etc, but is there anything I can do to keep sensitive info completely hidden from the front end? I don't want to use laravel/php or I'd just stay in WordPress.

Comment: There is no reason for any API keys that need to be kept secure to ever be on the front-end, ever.  Can you be more specific?  The answer to your problem currently is just "don't do it".

Comment: A few ideas I have are to use wordpress/formidable forms as a headless cms. The formidable forms api would have to be used with all ajax requests. The same goes for the storyblok management api that allows for crud operations.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the **problem** is, not what you think the solution is?

Comment: Sure. I'm thinking the problem would be a user being able to see the formidable or storyblok api on the front end and use it to make requests.

Comment: Cool, so don't make those requests from the front-end, make them from your back-end?

Comment: I didn't know I could do that with Vue/nuxt. I will have to research this some more. Feel free to leave any links you think would help. Thank you!

Comment: If you were to use Laravel and Storyblok then here’s a package for it: https://github.com/RicLeP/laravel-storyblok/